# Angular refresh redirect home/login under context path

Tags: angular

If I start angular app with `ng serve` all works fine. But if i start with `ng serve --serve-path contextpath/`, when I update the page in any place, it always redirects me to the home page. How can fix this?

I think it redirect me on **login page**, but i am login with modify header chrome extension

**This is my app-routing.module page**:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: "pages",
            loadChildren: () =>
                import("./pages/pages.module").then(
                    (m) => m.PagesModule
                ),
            canLoad: getLogginGuards()
        },
            path: "auth",
            loadChildren: () =>
                import("./auth/auth.module").then(
                    (m) => m.AuthModule
                )
        },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages/home' }
    ];
```

**getLogginGuards()**:

```
    export function getLogginGuards(): any {
      if (environment.securityOn)
        return [LoggedInGuard];
    }
    
    export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
        path !: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[];
        route !: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
    
    
        canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
            return BzUtils.getRplObs('isLogin', 1);
        }
    
        canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {
            return BzUtils.getRplObs('isLogin', 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you have implemented in getLogginGuards?

Comment: @ParthM.Dave just shared getLogginGuards code

Answer (score 0):

Solved using {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} in

app-routing.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Comment: Where i have to write this?

Comment: app.modules file 
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

Comment: It says "Cannot find name 'routes'"

Comment: sorry friend in your case you need to put code in app-routing.module page:

Comment: Done, but doesn't work, it always redirect me to home page :(

Comment: I added `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],`, but what is {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} and where i have to write this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249589/discussion-between-sweet-and-parth-m-dave).